# Performance: XMLDom vs XMLTable vs Extractvalue()

Tags: oracle, plsql, xml-parsing, database-performance

In Oracle, which one is faster in terms of accessing a  single value ?

`xmldom.getNodeValue(xmlNode);`

Or

`select extractvalue( XMLType('<nodeName>...'), '/nodeName/...') from dual`

Or XMLTable?
`Select *
From XMLTABLE ('nodeName',
    XmlType('<nodeName>)
         Columns — that 1 value);`